# Обязательное поле для заполнеия

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте!
Помогите реализовать следующий функционал:
Есть форма, где нужно, чтобы после активного чекбокса (нажали на него) поле, находящееся в форме стало обязательным для заполнения. 
Буду очень признательна!

```html
 <TD CLASS="browseItemName" NOWRAP VALIGN="TOP">
<INPUT TYPE="CHECKBOX" ID="_1_1_4_[LL_REPTAG=ROWNUM /]_5_1" NAME="_1_1_4_[LL_REPTAG=ROWNUM /]_5_1" value="1"  ONCLICK="EditPosition('_1_1_4_[LL_REPTAG=ROWNUM /]_7_1', '_1_1_4_[LL_REPTAG=ROWNUM /]_5_1');markDirty();">
</TD>
<TD CLASS="browseItemName" NOWRAP VALIGN="TOP">
<TEXTAREA CLASS="valueEditable multiline rfield" ID="_1_1_4_[LL_REPTAG=ROWNUM /]_7_1" NAME="_1_1_4_[LL_REPTAG=ROWNUM /]_7_1" TITLE="Reason" WRAP="soft" ROWS="3" COLS="128" READONLY="TRUE" ONCHANGE="markDirty();"></TEXTAREA>
</TD>
```

---

попыталась перенести на свой исходник код, не работает, в чем может быть причина ?

```js
function EditPosition(chk) {
  var edit = document.getElementById("test");
  if (chk.checked)
    edit.setAttribute("required", true);
  else
    edit.removeAttribute("required");
}
```

```html
<TD CLASS="browseItemName" NOWRAP VALIGN="TOP">

<INPUT TYPE="CHECKBOX" ID="_1_1_4_[LL_REPTAG=ROWNUM /]_5_1" NAME="_1_1_4_[LL_REPTAG=ROWNUM /]_5_1" value="1"  ONCLICK="EditPosition('_1_1_4_[LL_REPTAG=ROWNUM /]_7_1', '_1_1_4_[LL_REPTAG=ROWNUM /]_5_1');markDirty();" class="btn_submit disabled">

</TD>

<TD CLASS="browseItemName" NOWRAP VALIGN="TOP" ID="test">

<TEXTAREA CLASS="valueEditable multiline rfield" ID="_1_1_4_[LL_REPTAG=ROWNUM /]_7_1" NAME="_1_1_4_[LL_REPTAG=ROWNUM /]_7_1" TITLE="Reason" WRAP="soft" ROWS="3" COLS="128" READONLY="TRUE" ONCHANGE="markDirty();"></TEXTAREA>
</TD>
```

Comment: Код приложите чтобы пример было видно.

Comment: Молодец, что стараетесь улучшить вопрос.

Comment: Что имеется ввиду в фразе: "...чтобы после активного чекбокса (нажали на него) поле,..."?

Comment: последовательность действий, нажали на чекбокс и поле стало обязательным для заполнения

Answer (score 4):

```js
function updateRequired(chk) {
  document.getElementById("test").required = chk.checked;
}
```

```css
input[required]
{
  border: 1px red solid;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" onclick="updateRequired(this)" />
  <input type="text" id="test" name="test" />
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

```js
function EditPosition() {
  // stub
}
function markDirty() {
  // stub
}

$("tr td input[type='checkbox']").click(function(){
  var text = $(this).closest("tr").find("textarea");
  if (text.length > 0) {
    text[0].required = this.checked;
  }
});
```

```css
textarea[required] {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<TD CLASS="browseItemName" NOWRAP VALIGN="TOP">
<INPUT TYPE="CHECKBOX" ID="_1_1_4_[LL_REPTAG=ROWNUM /]_5_1" NAME="_1_1_4_[LL_REPTAG=ROWNUM /]_5_1" value="1"  ONCLICK="EditPosition('_1_1_4_[LL_REPTAG=ROWNUM /]_7_1', '_1_1_4_[LL_REPTAG=ROWNUM /]_5_1');markDirty();"/>
</TD>
<TD CLASS="browseItemName" NOWRAP VALIGN="TOP">
<TEXTAREA CLASS="valueEditable multiline rfield" ID="_1_1_4_[LL_REPTAG=ROWNUM /]_7_1" NAME="_1_1_4_[LL_REPTAG=ROWNUM /]_7_1" TITLE="Reason" WRAP="soft" ROWS="3" COLS="28" ONCHANGE="markDirty();" ></TEXTAREA>
</TD>
</tr>
</table>
<br/>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Обратите внимание на то, что я убрал `READONLY="TRUE"` из `TEXTAREA`.